# akntextutils and LFDM PyS60 Installation Help

Tags: s60, pys60

I came across a project LFDM and akntextutils at http://www.lfdm.net/thesis/index.php on the internet. However, i've failed
to install it on both my emulator and phone.

Could anyone help me with how I can install them on both the phone and my PC emulator? I tried
copying the source files to c:\system\libs on my computer and i still couldn't reference them on the emulator, then i tried c:\symbian..\winscw\c\system\libs and still i could reference them in my applications on the emulator.

I am currently running PyS60 version 1.4.5 final and the emulator I am currently running is Series 60 2nd Ed. FP3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LFDM seems to contain s60 3rd binaries for akntextutils. For 2nd edition binaries, go here: http://sites.google.com/site/ssalmine2/somepys60extensions. The correct package is: http://pymbian.sourceforge.net/misc/dashboard/dashboard-v.20051023.zip

That will contain 2nd ed binaries. Notice that for emulator and device the binaries are different. Emulator binaries are in wins directory, device binaries in armi directory.

Copy the akntextutils.pyd from wins directory to emulator symbian directory. I don't have 2nd ed emulator anymore so I don't remember the correct path. However, the correct path is somewhere under c:\symbian.

The c:\system\libs should be the correct one for device.

Comment: Hi Simo,
Thanks so much for your help and links. They've been helpful for getting akntextutils work. 

For the benefit of someone else, the folder on the emulator is C:\Symbian\8.1a\S60_2nd_FP3\Epoc32\winscw\c\system\libs

I am left with getting the LFDM working and I will be greater for any more help.